# Recurrence relation of the following sequence?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

This is the code:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            ++k;
```

And this is the output for when `n` and `k` start at `1` and `0` respectively:

\begin{array}{c|c}
n & k\\\hline
1 & 1\\
2 & 1\\
3 & 2\\
4 & 2\\
5 & 3\\
6 & 3\\
7 & 4\\
8 & 4\\
9 & 5\\
10 & 5\\
11 & 6\\
12 & 6\\
13 & 7\\
14 & 7\\
15 & 8\\
16 & 8\\
17 & 9\\
18 & 9\\
19 & 10\\
20 & 10\\
\end{array}

I need to express this as a sequence. Something like $a_n = ..$. How would I do this?

I know it would be something like $a_n = \frac{n}{2}$ when $n$ is even, and $a_n = \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$ otherwise but is there a different way?

Comment: It's simply only the $a_n = \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$. Why *even*-*odd*?

Comment: @m0nhawk Yeah that work's too. But WolframAlpha gives $a_n = \frac{1}{4}(2n - (-1)^n + 1)$. How can I get it to be something like that?

Comment: @m0nhawk Better yet, how can I get it to be a recurrence relation or something close?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you use the ++ prefix operator as opposed to the suffix?

Comment: @TylerHG Simply a personal preference. Here is doesn't make a difference but in other contexts they can have different effects.

Comment: Yes, I remember being confused when I first saw it used in a macro...had to look up the order of operations. Since then I've always stayed away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is as you mentioned

$$a_n=\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil$$

A different way of expressing this could be:

$$a_n=\frac n2+\frac12\!\left|\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)\right|$$

Derivation of above formula:

We start with the formula
$$a_n=\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil$$
When $n$ is even this is equal to
$$a_n=\frac n2$$
And when $n$ is odd this is equal to
$$a_n=\frac n2+\frac12$$

This means that if we find a function $f(x)$ that is equal to $0$ if $n$ is even and $\frac12$ when $n$ is odd then the following would be true.

$$a_n=\frac n2+f(x)$$

To find such a function, I'll use the periodicy of $\sin x$ meaning if $k$ is an integer then $\sin(\pi k)=0$

Another fact about the sine function is that $\sin\left(\pi\cdot\!\!\left(k + \frac12\right)\right)=\pm1$ where the $\pm1$ that for some integers it's $1$ and for others it's $-1$

Using these two facts we can deduce that

$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}2\right)$$

is zero for even $k$ and $\pm1$ for odd $k$, take the [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) and half it, you have our function $f(x)$

$$f(x)=\frac12\!\left|\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)\right|$$

---

Can also be written like this:

$$a_1=1$$
$$a_2=1$$
$$a_n=1+a_{n-2}$$

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. It's just that in my book the author goes through the steps to produce an equation from the sequence. How did you create that equation using `sin`?

Comment: @David I added a recursive formula

Comment: @David This formula should also work, can be derived similarely to the first $$a_n=\frac n2-\frac12\sin\left(\frac{3\pi n}2\right)$$ this formula avoids the absolute value.

Comment: Thanks! When you say $\sin(\pi k) = 0$ do you mean it is *approximately* equal to $0$? And likewise for $\sin(...) = \pm1$?

Comment: @David no, if you're using radians, those values exactly give 0 and $\pm1$